# Read MS Access file (.mdb) from Linux container

Tags: linux, ms-access, kubernetes, odbc

I'm trying to read an MS Access file (.mdb) from a Linux container in a K8S cluster.
This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:6.0 

ENV DOTNET_SYSTEM_GLOBALIZATION_INVARIANT=false

# install base libraries
RUN apt-get update -y && \
    apt-get install -y gnupg2 curl libpq-dev gcc g++ unixodbc-dev

# driver odbc
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add - && \
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/debian/11/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list && \
apt-get update -y && ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y msodbcsql17

# access
RUN apt-get install -y odbc-mdbtools

WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN rm appsettings.json
RUN chmod +x ./Tools.Access2PostgreSql
RUN rm -rf ./bin
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Tools.Access2PostgreSql.dll"]
```

Then, after I followed different guides, I update `odbc.ini` and `odbcinst.ini`:

```
[TestData]
Driver = MDBTools
Description = test
Database = /srv/access/data.mdb
```

```
[ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]
Description=Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server
Driver=/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.10.so.2.1
UsageCount=1

[MDBTools]
Description=MDBTools Driver
Driver=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libmdbodbc.so
Setup=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libmdbodbc.so
FileUsage=1
UsageCount=1
```

When I execute a simple query I have this error:

```
13:55:39 INF] Reader config: {"DatabaseConnectionString":"DSN=RoughnessMeter","PollingTime":"00:05:00","Machine":"RoughnessMeter","StartTime":null} {"SourceContext": "PBT004.AIM.Tools.FromAccessDbToMinIO.TriggerRunner"}
[13:55:39 INF] Now listening on: http://[::]:5000 {"EventId": {"Id": 14, "Name": "ListeningOnAddress"}, "SourceContext": "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime"}
[13:55:39 INF] Reader: [{"FieldCount":2},{"FieldCount":2},{"FieldCount":2},{"FieldCount":2},{"FieldCount":2},{"FieldCount":2},{"FieldCount":2}] {"SourceContext": "PBT004.AIM.Tools.FromAccessDbToMinIO.TriggerRunner"}
[13:55:39 ERR] Error: IdCodice    at System.Data.ProviderBase.BasicFieldNameLookup.GetOrdinal(String fieldName)
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataReader.GetOrdinal(String value)
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataReader.get_Item(String value)
   at PBT004.AIM.Tools.FromAccessDbToMinIO.TriggerRunner.TestQueryAsync() in /home/az-devops-agent/agent/_work/214/s/PBT004.AIM/PBT004.AIM.Tools.Access2PostgreSql/TriggerRunner.cs:line 100 null {"SourceContext": "PBT004.AIM.Tools.FromAccessDbToMinIO.TriggerRunner"}
```

using this connection string:

```
"DatabaseConnectionString": "DSN=TestData"
```

Here my `TestQueryAsync` method:

[image]

Any ideas to fix the problem?